# Python - writing in a file from an infinity loop

Tags: python-2.7

I want to log something with a python script.

```
while True:
    with open("logfile.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(time + " " + data + "\n")
```

But there is always the LAST message in the log on line 1. All data before is overwritten. 
I dont know how to write the messages line for line.

In every round of the whlie-loop the file is opened and closed. I think the cursor is always on line 1 when I open my file, right? And that is the problem.

But I tried everything with file.seek().. no chance.

Can someone help me?

Would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file in the append mode:

```
open("logfile.txt", "a")
```

Comment: That's it! Sorry, but I am absolutly beginner^^ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("logfile.txt", "w") as file:
    while True:
        file.write(time + " " + data + "\n")
```